# How to pass Realm Results around in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have UITableView view that queries a Realm db and lists its results. The query contains various filters and sorting directives.

When the user selects one of the table entries, they're taken to a detail view that allows them to swipe left or right to view the previous/next result from the query (in the same order they appear in the UITableView). This detail view is a separate ViewController and what I'm currently doing is passing the Results to the detail view controller so that it can move back and forth through them.

This worked great until the ability to delete items was introduced. Users can delete items, and I say users because someone else can delete an item and that deletion will propagate to all users (via the internet). Now, if a user has gone into the detail view, and someone deletes an item remotely, the Results set that was assigned to the detail view is now inconsistent. It doesn't get updated, even though the original Results in the table view does get updated.

I suspect this happens because the variable is assigned by value and not by reference.

When passing Realm Objects around, the recommended thing to do is to pass IDs and do the lookup again, but what to do when it comes to Results? Should I put the filtering/sorting code in a place that is accessible by both the UITableViewController and the detail controller so that they can both pull the results separately? Or, is there a better way that I'm ignoring?

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass Realm Results around in Swift?

You can pass `Results` instances directly. They are passed by reference and auto-update as described in the [Auto-Updating Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#auto-updating-results) section of Realm's Swift documentation.

You may also pass the `NSPredicate` or query string that represents the query to avoid the thread-confinement inherent to `Results`.

> Now, if a user has gone into the detail view, and someone deletes an item remotely, the Results set that was assigned to the detail view is now inconsistent. It doesn't get updated, even though the original Results in the table view does get updated.

Unless I'm misreading your post (which might be the case), this is not behaving correctly. If the thread on which the `Results` is confined to has a runloop (which is always the case on the main thread on iOS), and its parent `Realm` has [`autorefresh`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:vC10RealmSwift5Realm11autorefreshSb) enabled, then `Results` should always reflect the latest state of its Realm, which will be automatically advanced to the latest state across threads between each runloop iteration.

If one of the objects referenced by the query backing the `Results` has been deleted, the `Results` will then be empty, equivalent to its behavior if its query was [`FALSEPREDICATE`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW3).

If this does not match the behavior you're seeing, then you may have found a bug in Realm, in which case I'd encourage you to [file a GitHub issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new) so that Realm folks can investigate.